# Ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Tags: php, mysqli

Пишу систему регистрации и авторизации пользователей. Выбивает синтаксическую ошибку, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), в строке "if(numrows!=0)". Фигурные скобки и точки-запятые проверял в редакторе с динамической подсветкой (Atom), вроде всё на месте. Подскажите в чём проблема.

```php
    <?php

    if (isset($_SESSION["session_username"])) {
        header("Location: intropage.php");
    }

    if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
            $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
            $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usertb WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query)
        if ($numrows != 0) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];
            }
            if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
                $_SESSION['session_username']=$username;
                header("Location: intropage.php");
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid username or password!";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "All fields are required!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query) не поставили ;
Старайтесь писать код чисто, тогда подобные ошибки будут крайне легко находиться и вероятность их допущения будет минимальна.

Comment: mysqli_num_rows  i вроде на конце https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @Kirill , благодарю за помощь. Ошибку исправил, нашел ещё одну не закрытую фигурную скобку, да только исправил одну ошибку, вылезло ещё две по mysqli_query и mysqli_num_rows, сижу разбираюсь и колдую потихоньку =Р